# laravel nested relationships max()

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

**This code does not work. How is this possible?**

```
$product->variants()->promotions()->min('promotion_price');
```

relationships:

```
class Product extends Model
{
  public function variants(){
    return $this->hasMany(ProductHasVariant::class);
  }
}



class ProductHasVariant extends Model
{
  public function promotions()
  {
    return $this->morphedByMany(Promotion::class, 'variantable', 'product_variantables', 'product_variant_id', 'variantable_id');
  }
}
```

...................................

Comment: First of all, do you have any other table named variants, because I don't see anything that makes you name the Model **ProductHasVariant**.
2nd, your code is not that clear, but you can get product **loadMin('variants.products')**

Answer (score 0):

Your variants relation in product is return array object, you need get single object variants and then you can get promotion in ProductHasVariant. promotions in ProductHasVariant is return array object too, just do the same thing.

Or

you can do like this for test your relation model, but not good idea.

```
$product->variants()[0]->promotions()[0]->min('promotion_price');
```